# Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list - only works on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm having some problem searching full text in MySQL. The code below only works on my localhost, but on my hosted server it throws an error:

> "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list"

I've had various attempts, also tried to alter my table but the error still remains. Note that the code is working well on my localhost, and printing out actual results, however it fails on running it on live server.

This is my code:

```php
function relatedArticle($item, $category){
  global $con;
  $keywords = trim(removePrepositions($item));
  $keywords = str_replace(',','', $keywords);
  $keywords = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$keywords);
  $keyword_tokens = explode(' ', $keywords);
  $query_result = implode('+', $keyword_tokens);
  $construct = '';
  $construct = $query_result;
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM apps WHERE Match(title) AGAINST ('$construct' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) and active = 'active' and Type = '$category' limit 4";
  $query_result = $con->query($query) or trigger_error($con->error."[$query]");
  echo "<div id='Big_container_rel'>";
  echo "<div id='container_rel'>";
  while($row = $query_result->fetch_array()) {
    echo "<div id='container1_rel'>";
    $AdTitle = pre_replace($row['title']);
    $type = strtolower(pre_replace($row['Type']));
    echo "<a href='/".$type."/".$row['appId']."/".$AdTitle."/'><img id='imgMobi' alt=".$row['title']." src='uploads/".$row['image']."'/></a>";
    echo "<br/><h4><a href='/".$type."/".$row['appId']."/".$AdTitle."/'>".$row['title']."</a></h4>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
}
```

My `$construct` is returning text joined with '+' sign. For example , `find+fulltext+on+stack`
Please help avoid this problem; I tried several solutions from StackOverflow, but they haven't worked for me so please don't mark it as duplicate.

Comment: I would say it was fairly obvious that you hosted MYSQL is not setup the same as your local mysql

Comment: and what might be the cause?? Because it has disturbed me for over a week now trying to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks it has worked ... added  $queryt="ALTER TABLE apps ADD FULLTEXT(title)";
              $con->query($queryt);  and worked